# Show\hide input field by selecting dropdown list element |CakePHP 3

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp-3.0

my English is not very good, but I try to explain my problem.
I develop web-application using CakePHP 3.4.10 and begginer in web-develop al all.
This is a piece of my code

```
<div class="documents form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($document,['id'=>'doc_add']) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <h4><?= __('Add Document') ?></h4>

        <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('doc_type', ['label'=>'Document Type',
        'required'=> true,
        'type'=>'select',
        'options' => ['New', 'Again in work']
        ]);
        echo $this->Form->control('incoming_number');
        echo $this->Form->control('incoming_number_fraction',['disabled'=>true]);
        echo $this->Form->control('incoming_date');
        echo $this->Form->control('preparation_date');
        echo $this->Form->control('review_date');
        echo $this->Form->control('core_document');
        echo $this->Form->control('adult_id', ['options' => $adults]);
        echo $this->Form->control('document_view_id', ['options' => $documentViews]);
        echo $this->Form->control('infant_id', ['options' => $infants]);
        echo $this->Form->control('ref_action_id', ['options' => $refActions]);
        echo $this->Form->control('ref_article_id', ['options' => $refArticles]);
        echo $this->Form->control('ref_ministry_internal_affair_id', ['options' => $refMinistryInternalAffairs]);
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>         
</div>
```

What I want to do:
First user must select what type of document is inbox -
 If it is "New" - we should disable or hide field "incoming_number_fraction"
 If is is "Again in work" - we should  enable or show field "incoming_number_fraction"
And I want do this without press "Submit".
How does it on ? I spent many hours to find the solution, but nothing work for me(
If it is JQuery or JavaScript can anybody show how use it with CakePHP 3.x
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facepalm...post in here if anybody search.
**Using JQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#doc-type').change(function() {
    $('label[for=incoming-number-fraction], input#incoming-number-fraction').hide();
    if ($('#doc-type').val() == 1) {
        $('label[for=incoming-number-fraction], input#incoming-number-fraction').show();
    }
});
</script>
```